# How to handle nested promises?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, promise, angular-promise

I'm fairly new to the promises concept, at least at creating them. I've read documentation how they work and I get how *a* promise works. I also understand how you can trigger some callback when all promises are done, I just don't get it how to implement it in my code.

My code simplefied:

```
function start_it_all(){
    return $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, "SELECT foo FROM bar").then(function(result) {
        return anotherFunction();
    });
}
function anotherFunction(){
     return $http.get('foo.php').then(function(){
        // Here I get some data
     });
 }
```

Both the `$cordovaSQLite` and the `$http` are async. I need to be able to do this:

```
start_it_all().then(function(){
   // Hide Loading animation (no further return data needed).
});
```

I understand that the `.then()` are the promise handlers, but as I currently have it, it returns just the promise of the query, I want the `$http` to give the promise. At this point I get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined` on the `start_it_all().then()`

Can anyone explain how to do that?

Comment: I suspect something - before I expand on it, try `return Promise.resolve($cordovaSQLite.execute(db, "SELECT foo FROM bar")).then(` etc - i.e. wrap the promise returned by `$cordovaSQLite.execute` in `Promise.resolve()` - looks stupid, but, indulge me :p

Comment: I have wrapped the query in a `Promise.resolve()`, that fixed it.

Comment: Seems the promise returned by `$cordovaSQLite.execute` isn't quite a promise then - seen similar issue before in some other so called promise returned in some other library

Comment: I've posted an answer, the answer also "un nests" your code - should work, give it a go

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to `nest` those promises, you can do the following:

```
function start_it_all(){
    return $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, "SELECT foo FROM bar")
    .then(function(result) {
        return $http.get('foo.php');
    })
    .then(function(){
            // Here I get some data
    });
}
```

Based on the comments in the original question, the .then method of `$cordovaSQLite.execute` seems not to be Promise/A+ compliant

to fix this, wrap `$cordovaSQLite.execute(...)` in `Promise.resolve`

```
function start_it_all(){
    return Promise.resolve($cordovaSQLite.execute(db, "SELECT foo FROM bar"))
    .then(function(result) {
        return $http.get('foo.php');
    })
    .then(function(){
            // Here I get some data
    });
}
```

and, now, based on comment and edited question

```
function start_it_all(){
    return Promise.resolve($cordovaSQLite.execute(db, "SELECT foo FROM bar"))
    .then(anotherFunction)
    .then(function(){
            // Here I get some data
    });
}
```

> As pointed out by @LenilsondeCastro - in angular you can use `$q.when` above where I've used `Promise.resolve`

Comment: I don't think I can do your exact answer, as `start_it_all()` is in another file as `anotherFunction()` is, but the `Promise.resolve()` seems to fix it, thanks

Comment: In angular you can use `$q.when($cordovaSQLite.execute(db, "SELECT foo FROM bar"))` to wrap it as an angularjs promise

Comment: @LenilsondeCastro - good point, I failed to see the angular tag - but I prefer native Promises when possible for such simple tasks as fixing broken promises :p - but I've added a note to the answer

Comment: @JaromandaX not a problem at all, just a tip for scenarios where you don't have `Promise` or, perhaps, if you like keeping things in the "angularjs way".

Comment: About the `$q`, when working on websites, I prefer native JS over jQuery when possible, is this the same kind of situation?

Comment: Firstly, $q isn't jQuery, but, honestly, @Martijn it really doesn't matter in this case

Comment: I understand, I used jQuery as an example. `Promise` and `$q` are (here) the same, if that makes a difference?

Comment: @Martijn Yes native is mostly better, the angular `$q` is a [Promises/A+](https://promisesaplus.com/)-compliant implementation which follows the same specification of [ES6 Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). AngularJs uses an internal implementation because by the time the framework was created, native support to promises didn't exist yet. But it's up to you, doesn't matter much in this case.

Comment: for completeness - [$q](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) is based on [Q](https://github.com/kriskowal/q) which is Promise/A+ 1.0 compliant - there is a Promise/A+ 1.1 specification version. I've not been able to find what makes a Promise 1.1 vs 1.0 compliant, nor if ES6 Promise is 1.1 or 1.0 ...

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you *return* the promise at every level of the chain, and to return the data at the deepest level. So write:

```
    return $http.get('foo.php').then(function(){
        // Here I get some data
        return data;
    });
```

Edit: the above was written before you modified your question and added the `return`.

Then in the main call, you'd probably want to have access to the data, so add the argument:

```
start_it_all().then(function(data){
   // Hide Loading animation.
});
```

#### Error handling

In comments you indicated you got the `execute` promise back, ... this might indicate an error preventing the HTTP request from being made.

To be sure you are not running an undetected error condition, add the error handlers as well:

```
function start_it_all(){
    return $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, "SELECT foo FROM bar").then(function(result) {
        return anotherFunction();
    }, function(err) {
        console.log('error in SQL query', err);
    });
}
function anotherFunction(){
     return $http.get('foo.php').then(function(){
        // Here I get some data
        return data;
     }, function(err){
        console.log('error occurred in HTTP request', err);
     });
 }

start_it_all().then(function(){
    // ...
});
```

Comment: I've added it to my example as I do have that, but it still results in `TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined`. Are you sure this is the way to go? Because if that's the case, I'm gonna have to check other parts of the code :)

Comment: I am sure about this. Which `then` you get the error on?

Comment: Add a response argument to your $http promise callback : `then(function(response){ return response.data; });`

Comment: if the code in "here I get some data" is synchronus, you don't strictly need to return anything (same as return undefined any way) - the fact that this code is inside a then callback means it will be a promise that is ultimately returned from .then

Comment: Indeed, but then the *data* is lost, unless it is stored in (more) global variables, which is not that nice.

Comment: @trincot - the problem is, as I see it ... `$cordovaSQLite.execute` returns a promise ... check ... `$http.get` returns a promise ... check ... there is no code shown that could result in `TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined` - so data lost or not is irrelevant, the problematic part of the code has not been posted in the question

Comment: I have expanded my example a bit with another function. About the data, I dont care about it, I don't need it. All I need is the loading screen to fade out :)

Comment: You might have an non-trapped error condition. Check my update.

Comment: Turns out the the `.then()` of the query isn't a real promise, I don't 100% get *why*. Wrapping it in `Promise.resolve()` fixed that. Your certainty that the return in the return has to work stuck in my brain, won't be forgetting that for a while, thanks :)

Comment: as the data (return data) is never used down the promise chain, you don't strictly need to do that ... having no return inside a then callback will still return a promise ... the value resolved by that promise is `undefined` - but it's perfectly valid to do so